# Why can I not use @HostBinding on shorthand CSS grid properties?

Tags: angular, css-grid, angular2-hostbinding

When using `@HostBinding` on shorthand CSS grid properties (e.g. using `grid-row` instead of `grid-row-start` and `grid-row-end`) the bindings don't work:

```js
export class MyComponent {
  @HostBinding('style.grid-row')
  row = '1 / 2';
}
```

However using the individual properties does work:

```js
export class MyComponent {
  @HostBinding('style.grid-row-start')
  row = 1;

  @HostBinding('style.grid-row-end')
  row = 2;
}
```

Is this intentional or a bug with Angular? Of course a work around is to just not use the shorthand properties.

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qfotyg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are adding style directly to DOM, Angular consider the value as unstrusted. Use DomSanitizer to turn the unstrusted values into trusted value

**DomSanitizer**

> Sanitization is the inspection of an untrusted value, turning it into
>   a value that's safe to insert into the DOM. In many cases,
>   sanitization doesn't change a value at all. Sanitization depends on
>   context: a value that's harmless in CSS is potentially dangerous in a
>   URL.

```
export class AppGridCellBrokenComponent {
  @Input()
  text: string;

  @HostBinding('style.grid-row')
  get gridRow() {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(`${this.rowStart} / ${this.rowEnd}`);
  }

  @HostBinding('style.grid-column')
  get gridColumn() {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(`${this.columnStart} / ${this.columnEnd}`)
  }

  constructor(private sanitizer:DomSanitizer){

  }
}
```

[ForkedExample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xugflr)

[Ref](https://angular.io/guide/security#sanitization-and-security-contexts)